# Javascript Miscalculation and $NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, mathematical-optimization

I'm confused and I've tried getting the following javascript to render a **Total** amount calculation but I'm having $NaN and some cell are not displaying the correct values when a dropdown list is used to pick a mailing option.

Here's the Javascript and the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/2s9a4rh6/) that I've been working on:

```
$(function() {
  function calcTotal() {
    var p = {      
      qty: parseInt($(".prod-row .qty").text().trim()),
        costperitem: parseInt($(".prod-row .costperitem").text().trim()),
        tax: parseFloat($(".prod-row .tax").text().trim().slice(1)),
        shipcost: parseFloat($(".prod-row .shippingcost").text().trim().slice(1)),
        price: parseFloat($(".prod-row .item-cost").text().trim().slice(1))      
      };
      var t = 0.00;
      if (p) {
         t = (p.qty * p.costperitem) + (p.tax) + (p.qty * p.shippingcost);
      }
      console.log(p, t);
      return t;
    }
    $("#shippingmethod").change(function(e) {
        var shipQty = parseInt($(".prod-row .qty").text());
        var shipCost = parseFloat($(this).val());
            $(".prod-row .item-cost").html("$" + shipCost.toFixed(2));
            $(".prod-row .total").html("$" + (shipQty * shipCost).toFixed(2));
        var total = calcTotal();
        $("#product-totals .total").html("$" + total.toFixed(2));
   });
});
```

**Desired outcome**

To have all the items in only 1 row and where total column shows the following math result from the calculation: **(Qty. + ItemCost + Tax) + (Qty.*S&H)**.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(Qty. * ItemCost + Tax)...`?

Comment: Can't see `.costperitem` selector in your fiddle in which case it would be `undefined`

Comment: `shippingcost` is not a defined index, see here: `t = (p.qty * p.costperitem) + (p.tax) + (p.qty * p.shippingcost);`. It appears to be defined as `shipcost`

Comment: I've made some changes, but I still don't understand why all S&H is not changing by the total is.  S&H should display the total cost for shipping and handling, while Total column should display the sum of all the costs in the row. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue resides in the index call. In the following function:

```
function calcTotal() {
  var p = {      
    qty: parseInt($(".prod-row .qty").text().trim()),
    costperitem: parseInt($(".prod-row .costperitem").text().trim()),
    tax: parseFloat($(".prod-row .tax").text().trim().slice(1)),
    shipcost: parseFloat($(".prod-row .shippingcost").text().trim().slice(1)),
    price: parseFloat($(".prod-row .item-cost").text().trim().slice(1))      
  };
  var t = 0.00;
  if (p) {
    t = (p.qty * p.costperitem) + (p.tax) + (p.qty * p.shippingcost);
  }
  console.log(p, t);
  return t;
}
```

You reference `p.shippingcost` which does not exist and returns `undefined`.

Also, you want to `parseFloat()` on your `costperitem` section. `parseInt()` will round to the nearest Integer.

Also you need to `slice()` off any preceding `$` signs.

Correct like so:

```
function calcTotal() {
  var p = {      
    qty: parseInt($(".prod-row .qty").text().trim()),
    costperitem: parseFloat($(".prod-row .costperitem").text().trim().slice(1)),
    tax: parseFloat($(".prod-row .tax").text().trim().slice(1)),
    shipcost: parseFloat($(".prod-row .shippingcost").text().trim().slice(1)),
    price: parseFloat($(".prod-row .item-cost").text().trim().slice(1))      
  };
  var t = 0.00;
  if (p) {
    t = (p.qty * p.costperitem) + (p.tax) + (p.qty * p.shipcost);
  }
  console.log(p, t);
  return t;
}
```

Good Luck!

**Update**

I would suggest the following code that is fixed to perform all the various steps needed with the correct Class Names in place.

```
$(function() {
  function toCur(fl) {
    return "$" + parseFloat(fl).toFixed(2);
  }

  function parseCurToFloat(txt) {
    return parseFloat(txt.trim().slice(1));
  }

  function setNewShipCost($row, cost) {
    $row.find(".shipping-cost").html(toCur(cost));
    return toCur(cost);
  }

  function calcRowTotal($row) {
    var q = parseInt($row.find(".qty").text());
    var c = parseCurToFloat($row.find(".item-cost").text());
    var t = parseCurToFloat($row.find(".tax").text());
    var sh = parseCurToFloat($row.find(".shipping-cost").text());
    var ttl = (q * c) + (q * sh) + t;
    $row.find(".total").html(toCur(ttl));
    return ttl;
  }

  function calcNewTotal() {
    var t = 0.00;
    $(".prod-row").each(function(ind, el) {
      t = t + parseCurToFloat($(el).find(".total").text());
    });
    $("#product-totals .total").html(toCur(t));
    return t;
  }

  $("#shippingmethod").change(function(e) {
    var shipCost = $(this).val();
    console.log("Set Ship", setNewShipCost($(".prod-row"), shipCost));
    console.log("Calc Row Total", calcRowTotal($(".prod-row")));
    console.log("Calc total", calcNewTotal());
  });
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ag1u4vjc/

Comment: You've helped me creating this script! When the select goes to "Select an option", which should be the default then the S&H should be $0.00.  But instead I somehow messed up your previous script and the Item Cost is inheriting the default value of $0.00 and the total still shows $NaN.

Comment: @MarceloMartins Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/ag1u4vjc/

Comment: I appreciate your help Twisty.  There's still the issue with S&H displaying $2.95 on page load despite the dropdown displays the default "Select an option", which has a value of 0.00. S&H only goes to 0.00 once a different selection is made. As you choose the default "Select and option" then the S&H column will display 0.00.  However, that should be the default state. Can you help?

Comment: I've made a couple of modifications at http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/Lf9g3ax1/ but I'm still having issues with the default value when the page first load.

Comment: @MarceloMartins I am unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: @MarceloMartins if my answer has assisted you, I hope you will consider upvoting it. You may also consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: There're 2 issues to the http://jsfiddle.net/UXEngineer/Lf9g3ax1/, which are: 1- The Total is INCORRECT. The correct amount to be display under "Total" should be $5.76 instead of $5.39, and
2- When the Qty. is changed S&H should display the calculation of the Qty. * S&H Value (2.95, 3.50 or 4.67). Such values also need to be part of the "Total".

Comment: @MarceloMartins the issue is a Order of Operations issue. You're calculating the total before updating the tax. http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lf9g3ax1/73/

Comment: Ah! I think I got now!  Thanks very much for your help!